# 2013 Mac Excel: Can't Write Code in Visual Basic Editor

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to create a macro in the editor as what the internet suggests. However, as the screen shot shows, I cannot type anything on the right-hand side of the editor. None of the buttons on the lower side work either. Is this the correct way to write your code?
[image]

Comment: In the Windows version of Excel, you would either double-click on the "Sheet2 (D1)" line to show the code window for that object or you would right-click on that line and choose "View Code". Not sure if the Mac version works in the same way though

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the workbook where you wan to place the module, insert>module